# Bokeh 2.3.0: multi_line HoverTool shows source arrays instead of point coordinates

Tags: python, bokeh

I have several arrays containing X,Y and date values, each of these arrays being a line. I would like each X/Y/date to appear when hovering the points. For my project I do need to use `multi_line` instead of multiple `line` with bokeh  2.3.0.

So far I have defined tooltips as usual with lines, quads, etc…
But what I get in the tooltips are the arrays making up each line (picture and code below).

The expected tooltip in the picture below would be (xs:0, ys:1.47, color:green, date:2021-01-01) and not the full arrays.

Is there any way to display pointwise values instead of source arrays for each line ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

xs = [np.arange(0,10) for _ in range(3)]
ys = [(np.random.randn(10) + i).round(2) for i in range(3)]
dates = [pd.date_range("2021-01-01", "2021-01-10") for _ in range(3)]
colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(xs=xs, ys=ys, dates=dates, colors=colors))

p = figure(plot_width=750, plot_height=300)
p.multi_line(xs="xs", ys="ys", color="colors", source=source)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("xs","@xs"), ("ys","@ys"), ("color", "@colors"), ("date","@dates{%F}")]))

show(p)
```

[image: multi_line_hover]

Comment: I had the case of not getting the hovertool with any data, so clearly I'm doing something wrong. LOL

Comment: the hovertool for multi_line was broken around 2.2.0 and kind of fixed with 2.3.0

Comment: This looks like a Bug. Did you post this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh)?

Comment: Are you sure this example was working in an earlier release? On GibHub there is an realted [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7969) which is open since June 2018.

Comment: Nice, I hadn't seen this issue. This is exactly the problem I have.